What do the RC numbers on tap glands stand for?
I need to replace the tap glands on my bathroom hand basin taps. The water pressure is about 12ft head of water. The replacement units are stamped with RC numbers rc1 ... rc6, what do these numbers mean and what number should I use for the above application? I live in the UK.
